# Azure continuous integration with SQL migrations

Tags: .net, azure, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database

There is a nice article [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/) describing how to implement continuous integration on Azure.

But what if we have to update SQL schema of an SQL Azure instance that is used by multiple service roles as a part of deployment?

What is the best approach for managing this?
Should the service be stopped while migration is in progress? How to implement it with cmdlets?

P.S. for SQL migrations we prefer to use FluentMigrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article for managing more complex update domains and strategies:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781019.aspx

It is not specific to SQL Azure, but it does cover the overall architecture and your question about "should the service be stopped".